# Monitoring upload using uploadString in Firebase v9 error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

While upgrading from Firebase 8 to 9 I've hit a problem. I need to monitor the upload progress of *uploadString* but *uploadTask.on* seems to fail.

```
var uploadTask = uploadString(ref(this.$storage, 'profile.jpg'), canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8), 'data_url');

uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
  (snapshot) => {
    const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
  }, 
  (error) => {
    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
  }, 
  () => {
    // Handle successful uploads on complete
  }
);
```

The image gets uploaded but with the following error:

> "TypeError: uploadTask.on is not a function"

*uploadTask.on* with *putString* in version 8 works fine. Anyone know what is going on? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around for anyone interested, it works specifically for canvas elements and uses *uploadBytesResumable* instead. Still interested in how do achieve this with *uploadString* if anyone knows.

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8);
var file = now.dataURItoBlob(img);
var uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(ref(now.$storage, 'profile.jpg'), file);

uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
  (snapshot) => {
    const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
  }, 
  (error) => {
    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
  }, 
  () => {
    // Handle successful uploads on complete
  }
);
```

dataURItoBlob function is as follows

```
dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0){
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    }
    else{
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    }
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`uploadString()` returns an uploadTask.You use it to monitor the status of your upload

Comment: According to JS V9 [API reference for uploadString](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.md#uploadstring), it does not return `UploadTask`. It returns `Promise<UploadResult>`